# deploy war file on tomcat to iis

Tags: tomcat, iis

I deployed a **html file** on `tomcat` and host it to `IIS` with that way:

I installed `tomcat`, and I added a `html file` to `webapp folder`:

[image]

and in `IIS`, I created a new `site` called `Sample4` as bellow is presented:

[image]

--> As result, on `window server r2`, I got the content of `index.html` when accessing the url `localhost`.

My problem is that I'm stucked to do that with a **war file**.

Could you please help me getting that purpose ?.
Big thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we couldn't directly run the war file in the IIS. You need a Java EE Web Container such as Tomcat or JBoss in order to do so. IIS can just act as a front facing proxy for the stuff hosted through the WAR file

I suggest you could try to use below solution to run the war fo;e on Jetty and IIS is used as a proxy.

http://www.helicontech.com/articles/deploying-java-servlet-applications-on-windows-with-iis/